# Is there a specific formula for geometric sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

So the questions is asking me to come up with a formula for the following sequence.

```
8,  16, 32, 64, …
```

The answer they give is $A_n = 2^{n+2}$. When I looked at it, I saw $A_n = A_{n-1} \cdot 2$.

Is there something that makes my answer wrong? Is there a specific formula I should see when dealing with geometric sequences?

Comment: That is a geometric series...

Comment: Sorry about that, just fixed it. Same question though.

Comment: Were you asked for an explicit or a recursive formula?

Comment: Explicit formula

Comment: Your answer is technically correct, but only gives a recursion. For an explicit formula, telescope it down: $A_n= 2 A_{n-1}=2^2 A_{n-2}=2^3 A_{n-3}=\cdots=2^{n-1} A_1\,$.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is correct, but when only giving the recursion formula you need to define a starting point $A_0$. $A_0=4$ in your example, since the sequence 
$6, 12, 24, ...$ also is of the form $A_n=2\cdot A_{n-1}$, but with a different $A_0=3$.

Then you can also express your $A_0$ as $2^a$, in your example $a=2$ since $2^2=4=A_0$ giving the explicit formula.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, we have our series as $G = 8,16,32,\cdots $.  We have the first term as $8$ and the common ratio $r=2$ We now write the general term of this sequence $G $ as like what you have said with some manipulation is: $$G_n =8\times 2^{n-1}=2^3\times 2^{n-1}= 2^{n+2} ...(1)$$. We also get $$G_{n+1} = 2^{n+3}...(2) $$. Thus, we may express the $n+1$th term of $G $ in terms of the $n $th term as $$G_{n+1} =2G_{n}...(3) $$ But to the best of my knowledge the general term of a G.P is expressed as $(1) $ even though $(3) $ can be brought from $(1) $ as dxiv says in his comment by **telescoping**. The two forms are thus very much identical but just expressed in different ways.